# Mapping a spring form with a session object

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, mapping

I have a basic form and I got my values from sessionBean.person.xxxxx (so everything is OK):

```
<form:form action="account" method="post" class="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="sessionBean.person">
<!-- some form input elements like -->
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">E-mail</label><div class="col-md-4"><form:input cssClass="form-control" path="email" maxlength="64" /></div>
<!-- submit button -->
</form:form>
```

And a controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("sessionBean")
public class AccountController {
    @Autowired
    private SessionBean sessionBean;

    /** Display account page and process updates: password, personnal information, company, delivery and billing addresses
     * @return JSP name
     */
    @RequestMapping("/account")
    public String accountPage(/* request params */) {
        //checks not displayed
        Person p=sessionBean.getPerson();
        s.createQuery("UPDATE Person SET tittle=:t, firstname=:fn, lastname=:ln, phone=:p, fax=:f, email=:e  WHERE id=:id")
            .setParameter(":t", p.getTitle())
            .setParameter(":fn", p.getFirstname())
            .setParameter(":ln", p.getLastname())
            .setParameter(":p", p.getPhone())
            .setParameter(":f", p.getFax())
            .setParameter(":e", p.getEmail())
            .setParameter(":id", p.getId())
            .executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

The sessionBean is:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9139554982970790165L;
    private final String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private Person person = null;
    private String redirect=null;
    private Order3d order3d=new Order3d();
    //getter and setters
}
```

My Person class is:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3005461811554821039L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column (name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column (name="company")
    private String company;
    @Column (name="siret")
    private long siret;
    @Column (name="payment")
    private String payment;
    @Column (name="title")
    private String title;
    @Column (name="firstname")
    private String firstname;
    @Column (name="lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @Column (name="password", columnDefinition="char", length=64)
    private String password;
    @Column (name="phone")
    private String phone;
    @Column (name="fax")
    private String fax;
}
```

When I get my Person object in my controller, typed values are not updated in sessionBean.peron :(

Comment: Can you fill in what values you are passing into `accountPage()`?

Comment: Also, I am not sure what you mean by "typed values".  Are you saying none of the properties of the `Person` you edit in the form get updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it, I forgot to add a parameter :

```
public String accountPage(@ModelAttribute("sessionBean") SessionBean sb);
```